# If Lord Krishna lives in Goloka Vrindavana where do the other avataras live?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, avatars, lokas, vaikuntha

Lord Vishnu lives in Vaikuntha while his poorna avatara Lord Krishna lives in Goloka Vrindavana. Do any of the other Vishnu avataras have their own lokas? If yes, please mention the names of these lokas and their respective Lords.

Comment: I think there's no universal belief on this. But it is said Rama lives in Saketapuri which is also other name of earthly Ayodhya.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Can you quote from which scripture it is said that Rama lives in Saketa?

Comment: I don't know which scriptures mention Cosmic Saketapuri.

Comment: It is said that Goloka is the highest planet in Vaikuntha. Just because Krishna lives on Goloka and Narayana on other parts of Vaikuntha it doesn't mean that various forms of Vishnu cannot appear or live on different locations of Vaikuntha and Goloka. I don't know all the details but it could be that particular form of Lord Vishnu has his own specific place of residence in Vaikuntha. Thus Narayana lives in Vaikuntha, Krishna on Goloka, Rama in Ayodhya, Sadasiva on Sadasivaloka, etc.

Comment: Every parabramha swarupa is said to have their own loka which a true devotee reaches upon salvation. Subrahmanya, Surya etc. all have lokas.

Comment: Sri Rama lives in Saket Loka within Vaikuntha

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar Lol were you stalking me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are references to various places where the Avataras of Vishnu reside.  Varaha Avatara resides in a sumptuous palace on Mount Meru. There is reference to this Skanda Purana under the Chapter Venkatesha Mahatmyam. I have no idea or reference to the worlds of Narasimha and Vaamana, but Parshurama still resides on the earth.

If more clarifications or references do come to me, I will further update.